# Git workflow tracking project with own custom changes

Tags: git

I have been trying and Googling/Stackoverflowing for a good solution, but still haven't found it. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

I use MantisBT to track issues. For some customers I would like to make some changes to this project.

Now I can download each new version when it comes out, and manually insert my changes. But I think it is probably possible to fork MantisBT, make my changes, and pull in all changes from MantisBT repository.

The problem I'm facing is that when I merge from upstream, I still have to manually insert my changes, because when I git checkout release-1.2.17 (latest stable release) it gives me the original upstream code (since tag is commit based).

How do I go about? I would like to have two "master" branches, one following upstream exactly (so I can get the official releases), and one that "tracks" upstream, but incorporates any custom changes I want to make as well. And it would nice if git checkout release-1.2.17 would give me that official release with my custom changes.

Apologies if this question turned more into rambling than asking...

[Git workflow for maintaining an project extension fork?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148701/git-workflow-for-maintaining-an-project-extension-fork) - Suggests the structure to use for branching, but doesnt tell me how to get release 1.2.17 from my custom branch.

Comment: It sounds like you want to merge, not checkout.

Comment: But when I merge, the tag "release-1.2.17" doesnt point to my customized branch. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to have two "master" branches,
>
> - one following upstream exactly (so I can get the official releases),

You don't need it: it is called `upstream/master` (provided you add a git remote named "upstream" and referencing the original repo (the one you have forked)

```
git fetch upstream
```

> - and one that "tracks" upstream, but incorporates any custom changes

You can create one starting from the tag you want:

```
git checkout -b master release-1.2.17
```

Then you can merge any updates from `upstream/master` to that master branch whenever you want to include new evolutions from upstream.

Comment: Ok, so I can use upstream as my "vanilla" branch. And I use the release-1.2.17 tag to start my own master branch, in which I incorporate my customizations. Now MantisBT has a new release, and they tagged it release-1.2.18. When I merge from upstream to my master, that tag is lost. Or was it lost because I used a local "vanilla" branch, which I merged into my "custom" branch?

Comment: @qrazi that is there (on the `upstream/master` branch). You don't need it on your `master`. You can simply add to the merge commit a message "`merged from 1.2.18`".

Comment: Forgive my slowness of mind, but I shouldnt merge on every oportunity I get, but specifically merge on the release commits, which I can then tag myself for future reference?

Comment: @qrazi sure: I never said otherwise in my previous comment. I just said you will see the tag on the `upstream/master` branch. Not on your `master` branch.

Comment: ok, so tactically merging seems the way to go to give my own tags on my own branch to mirror the release tags on upstream. And merges in between is not a problem either in that workflow. Thank you for explaining, I'm going to try and set this up!